# How to check if some post is liked by User in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have `posts`, `users` and `favorites` table.
For example, I make some post favorited for a user with an id of 3 like this :

```
User::find(3)->favorites()->attach($post->id);
```

and if users send request twice it will insert this favorite with this `post_id`, `user_id` twice.
I want to check if a post is not liked by this user, then save record in the database.
or if a post is favorited then unfavorite it.
how can I do this with eloquent relationship ??
I have `User`, `Post` models.

Comment: use query method https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `toggle()`:

```
User::find(3)->favorites()->toggle($post->id);
```

This would like it if it not liked, and unlike it if it is.

If you just want the function not to duplicate likes in the table, just use `syncWithoutDetaching`:

```
User::find(3)->favorites()->syncWithoutDetaching([$post->id]);
```

Putting this on your User model:

```
class User extends Model {

  public function like($postId){
    $this->favorites()->syncWithoutDetaching([$post->id]);
  }

  public function unlike($postId){
    $this->favorites()->detach([$post->id]);
  }
}
```